# How do I change text with a prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prefab

how do I  make and change text inside a c# script?

I have this code currently but it does not work because I tell the script what the text I want to change is:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class treeBreak : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float woodCount = 0; 
    public Text woodText;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if (other.CompareTag("sword")){
        Destroy(gameObject);
        woodCount = woodCount + 1;
        }    
    }
    void Update(){
        woodText.text = woodCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work at all as you're destroying the total wood count with the object.  Did you mean to have a static woodCount?

Comment: At some point you have to link your UI with the things it counts. It's easier if your rarely-changing UI keeps track of the often-changing game objects rather than the other way around.  I can definitely recommend checking out the tutorials that Unity provide on their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems. First if you destroy the object you lose the woodCount field because it will be destroyed with the object. Second if the object is destroyed the Update method never execute so the text wont update.

Solution 1:
The faster way to fix this is you make the woodCount [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). And you update the text in the  OnTriggerEnter2D.

```
public class treeBreak : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float woodCount = 0; // Stick with the class.
    
    public Text woodText;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("sword"))
        {
            woodCount = woodCount + 1;
            woodText.text = woodCount.ToString();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Solution 1:
The better way if you separate the game logic from the UI... for example:

```
public class TreeBreak : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public WoodCounter woodCounter;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("sword"))
        {
            woodCounter.Collect();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

public class WoodCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text woodText;

    private int woodCount = 0;

    public void Collect()
    {
        woodCount++;
        woodText.text = woodCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

PS: woodCount should be an integer if you only increase by one

Answer (score 0):

Try to swap these two lines

```
woodCount = woodCount + 1;
Destroy(gameObject);


private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if (other.CompareTag("sword")){
          woodCount = woodCount + 1;
          woodText.text = woodCount.ToString();
          Destroy(gameObject);
        }   
}
```

Comment: Still wouldn't work. You need to *change the text* before the destroy happens.  Currently, that change only occurs in ```Update``` and there's no guarantee that the update will run before the destroy.

Comment: Oh you are right so did you try without update ? @Immersive

Comment: What do you mean?